# How do I completely delete all history and data from Samsung Galaxy tablet?

Tags: cyanogenmod

I want to sell my Samsung Galaxy tablet after getting a new iPad from work.  I've done the reboot / factory reset to erase my personal info and history, but my photos and contacts are still showing.  Is it possible to erase EVERYTHING in order to sell it? I don't want anyone being able to access my previous accounts or information.

Comment: Well, the contacts are still showing because you may have put your gmail account back in the device I would say try heading over to the settings>accounts and Sync>Tap over Gmail> Remove the Google Account and then again format the device. Now this time don't put the Google account when the device ask for and the contacts won't show up !

Answer (score 1):

Just goto your dial pad and enter ***2767*3855#** 
your device will then reset itself and erase all your personal informations and settings.

This page will help you to do factory restore your Samsumg Galaxy Tab through Main menu as well as Hard key reset.

http://galaxytablettalk.com/galaxy-tab-tutorials/how-to-reset-samsung-galaxy-tab-to-factory-settings

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to clear application data permanently to  delete all your user information, settings, high scores, and credit card information - anything that you didn't originally download with the application.

You have to follow these simple steps:

1. From the home screen, tap the All Apps icon.
2. Scroll to and tap Settings.
3. Tap the General tab & tap Application manager.
4. Swipe left to the All tab.
5. Scroll to and tap the preferred application.
6. Tap Clear data.
7. Review the message and tap OK.

For more details you can also go to Samsung India site and check in support option.

Answer (score 0):

In your accounts and synch , please remove all your accounts and then do a factory reset. If this does not work then do a hard reset.

Instructions for hard reset

- Ensure that the Samsung tablet is powered off.
- Press the Power and the Volume Up button together till the device
  displays the start-up logo.
- Once the logo is displayed, release the buttons and wait till the
  device enters the Android system recovery mode.
- On the displayed screen, use Volume Down button to go to the wipe
  data/factory reset option (Volume Up and Volume Down buttons are used
  to highlight the displayed options on the Android system recovery
  screen).
- Once the option is highlighted, press the Power button to select the
  option. (Pressing the Power button in Android system recovery mode
  selects the highlighted option.)
- On the next screen, press the Volume Down button multiple times till
  the Yes -- delete all user data option is highlighted.
- Press the Power button to hard reset the Samsung tablet device, which
  will also clear the dalvik cache.

[**SOURCE FOR HARD RESET**](http://www.tomsguide.com/faq/id-1765863/hard-reset-samsung-galaxy-tablet.html)